# json_decode Error "Undefined property: stdClass::$option_value"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get data saved in json format inside database column

Data:

```
[ 
   { 
      "option_value":"Delhi",
      "optionl2_value":"\u0926\u092f\u093e\u0930\u093e\u092e \u0938\u093e\u0939\u0928\u0940",
      "has_file":0,
      "file_name":""
   },
   { 
      "option_value":"Panjab",
      "optionl2_value":"\u0930\u093e\u0916\u0932\u0926\u093e\u0938 \u092c\u0928\u0930\u094d\u091c\u0940",
      "has_file":0,
      "file_name":""
   }
]
```

and here is the code i'm using.

```
    @if(is_array(json_decode($question->answers)))
      @foreach ( json_decode($question->answers) as $value) 
        <span> {{ $value->option_value }}</span><br>
      @endforeach
    @endif
```

and I get the following error

**> Error : Undefined property: stdClass::$option_value**

How can I resolve?

Comment: so why dont you debug what `$value` is in the loop so you can figure out why that property doesn't exist

Comment: @lagbox when i tried this "{{ $value }}" i got this error "Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Comment: Edit post and add `var_dump($question->answers)` result.

Comment: How you are getting value `$question->answers` ?

Comment: [{"option_value":"Delhi","optionl2_value":"\u0926\u092f\u093e\u0930\u093e\u092e \u0938\u093e\u0939\u0928\u0940","has_file":0,"file_name":""},{"option_value":"Panjab","optionl2_value":"\u0930\u093e\u0916\u0932\u0926\u093e\u0938 \u092c\u0928\u0930\u094d\u091c\u0940","has_file":0,"file_name":""}]

Comment: I find the solution

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 <?php
    $data = json_decode($jsondata);   
 ?>
<ul>
   @foreach($data as $value) 
    <li> {{ $value->city}}</li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```